# Using gcc/clang C extensions to test if a macro argument is a pointer

Tags: c, gcc, clang, gcc-extensions

Using gcc/tcc/clang's extensions to the C language (C11), is it possible to detect whether
a macro argument has a pointer type?

Details:
I'm using a macro that should take a singly-indirect pointer, but it's tempting to pass a pointer to that pointer because that's what the corresponsing "constructor" macro takes, but doing so would be an error, so I'm currently currently using something like:

```
  #define ISPTR(X) (sizeof(X)==sizeof(void*)&&_Alignof(X)==_Alignof(void*)) /*inaccurate*/

   #define TAKE_SINGLY_INDIRECT(P) do{ _Static_assert(!ISPTR(*(P)), "pass a singly indirect pointer"); /*...*/ }while(0)
```

to protect myself from myself. Is there a better way to implement `ISPTR()`?

Comment: Sorry, I think I miss understood your question. Can you give the use case code, your description is not clear for me.

Comment: Just include a statement like `P[0];` and it will fail compilation for not a pointer (but might trigger UB is `P` is not pointing anywhere).

Comment: @EugeneSh. It seems that compilation should fail if `P` is not a single indirection pointer.

Comment: @VTT Oh. Now that's complicated.

Comment: I think it is only possible when passing target type as macro parameter. Then it can be checked with `__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(P), TARGET *)`

Comment: @VTT Exactly. `ISPTR(*(P))` should statically evaluate to false iff `*(P)` is a nonpointer type. I don't think it's a duplicate with the suggestion cuz differentiating ptr and arrays is a different matter (not to mention if C++ is allowed too).

Comment: @VTT It should be a type-generic macro. I can't think of a solution either, hence the question.

Comment: I think we got a xy problem, I don't see why in the word you need that, please again give real use case. The code inside your macro should not compile or at least produce warning itself with a double pointer. And why use macro ??? Don't you like function ?

Comment: `Is there a better way...` Indeed there is a better way. It is called "test". You implement a separate program that run your code and check whether or not the output is legit according to your specification. The method is cross platform and tool independent, compatible with every version of every programming language ever. (Please stop undermining proper testing by "clever" compiler hacks. No offence)

Comment: @PSkocik Do you know the expected pointer type, or is it unknown (i.e. `T *` for some arbitrary `T`)?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer unknown

Comment: You could do something like `#define WARN_IF_NOT_PTR(X) { void * make_uniq_name = X; }` or even define a function taking a ptr arg... basically you just want to invoke the type checker, right?